# AgentSpeak: Problems at sending plan (Jason)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, agent

I'm trying to send a plan from Agent1 to Agent2 via:

```
@c2[atomic] 
+giveRule[source(A)]: planGiven(B) <-
                -+planGiven(B+1);
                .send(A, tellHow, "@s1 +sum(num1(X, Y), num2(A, B))[source(S)] :logic(L) & attentiveness(T)<- if ((L + T) > 2){ -+res(num1(X, Y), num2(A, B), res(X*10 + A*10 + Y + B)); .send(S, tell, result(X*10 + A*10 + Y + B)); } else { -+res(num1(X, Y), num2(A, B), res(X + A + Y + B)); .send(S, tell, result(X + A + Y + B)); }.");
                -+stopGivingPlan.
```

Then, i'm trying to make this plan work by sending a message from Agent1 to Agent2:

```
@c3[atomic]
+giveProbs[source(A)]: probsGiven(B) & stud(A,X)<-
                -+probsGiven(B+1);
                .send(A, tell, sum(num1(3,3), num2(4,9))).
```

It doesn't work.
Why?

And important addition:
If I don't send plan, and just copy it in Agent2, it works fine. so Syntax is ok.

Also, i'm using jason plugin in eclipse, if that's worth to be mentioned.

Comment: Either I'm *way* behind the times, or that's not Java. So... what is it?

Comment: Sorry, there's just not enough tags. It's AgentSpeak

Comment: You might want to mention that in the question.

Comment: @BitNinja: [Apparently not](http://jasonplugin.wikidot.com/)!

Comment: Look at Sniffer example in Jason libraries , you can find your answer there. similar to :   `p1 ->
    te1(t) :
      c1(y) <-
        .send(ag2,tellHow,"p2 -> te2(t) : c2(t) <- a2(t).").`

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what is being performed, it is better if you can show the whole code. I simplified the case just to try to show a general idea, as bellow:

Agent1 code:

```
!start.

+!start: true <-
    .send(agent2, tellHow, "@s1 +!sum(num1(X, Y), num2(A, B))[source(S)] :true <-  -+res(num1(X, Y), num2(A, B), res(X + A + Y + B)); ?res(Z1,Z2,Z3); .print(Z1,\"+\",Z2,\"=\",Z3).");  
    .send(agent2, achieve, sum(num1(1,2), num2(3,4))).
```

Agent2 code:

```
/* No previous code - agent1 will send a plan*/
```

The response should be:

```
[agent2] num1(1,2)+num2(3,4)=res(10)
```

In this case, agent2 has nothing to do until agent1 sends a plan. Agent1 is also sending a triggering plan to achieve a sum.